# How many times functions can be deployed per project?

Tags: google-cloud-functions

visit resource limits - https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas

Number of functions : The total number of functions that can be deployed per project- 1000 limit.

its means 1000 separated functions can deployed or each function deployed 1000 versions?

Comment: 1000 separated functions. Otherwise it would be described as number of functions deployments. So, when you create a Cloud function you set a name let's say Function1.  After that , you are able to create another 999 Cloud functions.

Comment: @TasosV okay i understand. but, how many versions can i deployed each functions?

Comment: Frank van Puffelen@ explained it perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be no more than 1,000 active exported Cloud Functions per project.

The number of deployments is not relevant to this limit. But if you ever have more than 1,000 active, exported functions in a single deployment, that deployment will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Whichever that comes first, same thing....Per project the limit is 1,000 times or versions total in one project.

Then each function size must be <= 100MB for sources and <= 500MB for sources plus modules.

Check [here for more.](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas)